# Not debugging properly in C (Eclipse Mars)

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

I'm beginner for **C  language** and for **Eclipse IDE**. I've downloaded and installed Eclipse ide for c/c++ developers i.e. Mars 2.0. I've created a new project and selected the appropriate compiler and typed the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("Hello, World! \n");
  return 0;
}
```

After, when click build project it creates .exe file for me and when I click on Debug it successfully Debugs but *shutdowns automatically within a fraction of a second*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've told us, that would be correct.  If you want to step through the code, you have to set a breakpoint.  You should be able to double-click in the margin on the "printf" line to set a breakpoint there.

Comment: I hope you have understood the question ;) What I'm trying to tell is that, suppose I've created a Console project in C# and debug it, the Console window waits for us to reply before it stops debugging, but here I'm not getting anything it just shuts down. Why it is like that.

Comment: I'll say it again. If you execute the program in debug mode without setting a breakpoint, it won't stop until the program completes.  Set a breakpoint first.